# Foreign key not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I know its not "The Rails Way" but I'm trying to add foreign keys to enforce referential integrity at the db level.  I want to create a new table called recipe_ingredients which will have foreign keys referencing a table called recipes and one called ingredients.  Here is my migration:

```
class CreateRecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipe_ingredients do |t|
      t.references :recipe, null: false
      t.references :ingredient, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :recipe_ingredients, :recipes
    add_foreign_key :recipe_ingredients, :ingredients
  end
end
```

The migration succeeds and generates the following:

```
                                                          Table "public.recipe_ingredients"
    Column     |            Type             |                            Modifiers                            | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('recipe_ingredients_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 recipe_id     | integer                     |                                                                 | plain    |              |
 ingredient_id | integer                     |                                                                 | plain    |              |
 measurement   | character varying           | not null                                                        | extended |              |
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null                                                        | plain    |              |
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null                                                        | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "recipe_ingredients_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_176a228c1e" FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES recipes(id)
    "fk_rails_209d9afca6" FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredients(id)
```

The problem is that when I try to create a new recipe_ingredient with an invalid recipe_id and/or ingredient_id it still considers it valid.  How can I get the db to enforce referential integrity on these fields?  I am using a postgresql db.

Comment: Those FKs should be enforcing referential integrity. Who considers these invalid rows as valid? And why aren't the `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` columns also `not null`?

Comment: What do you mean by valid? If the model says it's valid it's because there are no validations there, it doesn't mean that you can insert it into the db.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  I was using `.valid?`, which of course only runs the validations IN the model.  It works correctly when I try to save to the db.  Thanks @Iceman :-)

Comment: No prob, I made an answer so this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `valid?` only runs the validations on the model, it's not until you try to actually insert it into the db that the referential integrity checks kick in there.

In [Rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html), having `belongs_to` in your model automatically requires the parent to exist.

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

You can opt out of this with

```
belongs_to :parent, required: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily say this isn't the "Rails way". I like to think of using FKs and model validation like wearing a belt and suspenders. For those times you really don't want your pants falling down.